# Highlight specific date when datepicker shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have this simple datepicker jQuery, and in my application my users can go back to the past, but not future. I want to show the current day base on the date param in the url browser.

Let's say

```
var url_string = window.location.href;
var url        = new URL(url_string);
var dateParam  = url.searchParams.get("date"); <<----- current date
```

## I have

```
$(".clock").click(function() {

    $( "#expiryDate" ).datepicker('setDate', date); <<---- Note here 

    $("#expiryDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        defaultDate: date,
        showAnim: "fold",
        gotoCurrent: true,
        maxDate: 0,
        onSelect: function() { 

            var dateSelected = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); 
            dateSelected = moment(dateSelected).format('YYYY-MM-DD');


            // $( "#expiryDate" ).datepicker('setDate', dateSelected);

            playSound('forward');

            if(dateParam == null) {
                var url = document.location.href+"&date="+dateSelected;
            }else {
                var url = document.location.href;
                url = url.replace(dateParam,dateSelected);

            }

            document.location = url;
        }
    });


    $('#expiryDate').datepicker('show');
});
```

Even if today is `05/06/2021`, users can go back to the past, and see what happened on that day. So when user selected `02/03/2021`. I want to highlight that date `02/03/2021`. It seems working only if I clicked on my date twice.

Notice only second clicked `3` started to highlight!

[image]

How do I make it highlight on first clicked ?

Comment: Put this line `$( "#expiryDate" ).datepicker('setDate', date);` before `$('#expiryDate').datepicker('show');`

Comment: Isn’t it already before ? It’s ok the first line after onClick

Comment: That line should be after you intialize your datepicker .

Comment: Ok, let me try and will share result after.

Comment: Could you please add a [mre]? It's almost impossible for us to debug the code.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to highlight that date 02/03/2021. It seems working only if I clicked on my date twice.

---

If removed the following code:

```js
var dateSelected = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); 
dateSelected = moment(dateSelected).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

This can easily be replaces by the `onChange` function parameter, for more info, take a look at the [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Replaced by:

```js
onSelect: function(dateSelected) {
```

---

With that in mind, I've created some sort of [mre] from the code above. This seems to work as expected:

1. The `url_string` date is selected on load
2. On press, the new date is highlighted instantly

```js
var url_string = 'https://example.com?date=2021-05-02';    // DEBUG
var url        = new URL(url_string);
var dateParam  = url.searchParams.get("date");
console.log('dateParam', dateParam);

$(".clock").click(function() {

    $("#expiryDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        defaultDate: dateParam,
        showAnim: "fold",
        gotoCurrent: true,
        maxDate: 0,
        onSelect: function(dateSelected) { 
            console.log('onSelect', dateSelected);

            if (dateParam == null) {
                var url = document.location.href+"&date="+dateSelected;
            } else {
                var url = document.location.href;
                url = url.replace(dateParam,dateSelected);
            }
        }
    });

    $('#expiryDate').datepicker('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class='clock'>
  <div id='expiryDate' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shooting a bit in the dark for now, since we have low info:

According to your snippets:

```
var dateParam  = url.searchParams.get("date"); <<----- current date
```

And

```
$( "#expiryDate" ).datepicker('setDate', date); <<---- Note here
```

The problem is that you define `dateParam` while you use `date`.

It's hard to tell if other code define the `date` variable, but as a starter, I'd make sure that your date is correctly set...

```
console.log(date); // Make sure it logs the correct date.
$( "#expiryDate" ).datepicker('setDate', date); <<---- Note here
```

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the lifecycle of the datepicker. The datepicker will be initialized as

```
$("#expiryDate").datepicker({});
```

If you call

```
$("#expiryDate").datepicker('setDate', date);
```

Before the datepicker be initialized, that will nothing to do with it at the first time.
At the second time, because of the datepicker was initialized. So, everything works fine. Moreover, once you set the date, it not needs to default date.

Due to reasons of above, the code should be modified as

```
$(".clock").click(function() {
    $("#expiryDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        showAnim: "fold",
        gotoCurrent: true,
        maxDate: 0,
        onSelect: function() { 

            var dateSelected = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); 
            dateSelected = moment(dateSelected).format('YYYY-MM-DD');


            // $( "#expiryDate" ).datepicker('setDate', dateSelected);

            playSound('forward');

            if(dateParam == null) {
                var url = document.location.href+"&date="+dateSelected;
            }else {
                var url = document.location.href;
                url = url.replace(dateParam,dateSelected);

            }

            document.location = url;
        }
    });

    $("#expiryDate").datepicker('setDate', date); <<---- Note here 
    $("#expiryDate").datepicker('show');
});
```